# how to query SQL dts package

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, dts

I have dts pacakege both in SQL & file system (.dts file). I want to query both the packages to retreieve information like number of package name, task information (task name etc).

What is the right way to do this?

I tried executing the command which gives list of dts package. However I don't know how to retrieve rest of the information.
exec msdb..sp_enum_dtspackages

Atul

Comment: use `msdb..sysdtspackages`

Comment: Thanks for ur response, I executed following queries, however only first one returns data, for rest of the query no row is returned. select * from msdb..sysdtspackages -- This return data
select * from msdb..sysdtscategories
select * from msdb..sysdtspackagelog
select * from msdb..sysdtstasklog
select * from msdb..sysdtssteplog
Also how to get information about standalone dts file.

Comment: I got this link to query the standalone package, however I am not able to register "Microsoft DTSPackage Object Library", I tried registering it gives this error message "The module "dtspkg.dll" was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x8002801c" msdn link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241249

Comment: Check http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2009/10/18/collecting-information-about-your-ssis-packages-ssis-nugget.aspx and http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1089382-147-1.aspx to query `ssis packages`

Comment: Thanks again, These links query SSIS package (.dtsx), I want to query dts (SQL 2000) package

Comment: You can use the [DTS Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa176058(v=sql.80).aspx) to query packages directly from any language that supports COM. But DTS is really an outdated technology, and SQL 2000 is no longer supported, so you should plan to upgrade and migrate your packages to SSIS.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem a while ago and found my answer. Please have a look at my script and see if it is of any use.

```
dim strInputFile, strOutputFile

for each arg in WScript.Arguments
    select case mid(arg, 1, 3)
        case "/i:"
            strInputFile = mid(arg, 4)
        case "/o:" 
            strOutputFile = mid(arg, 4)
    end select
next

dim oPackage
set oPackage = CreateObject("DTS.Package2")
oPackage.LoadFromStorageFile strInputFile, "", "", "", ""

dim FileSys, OutputFile
set FileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set OutputFile = FileSys.OpenTextFile (strOutputFile, 2, 1)

dim oTasks, oProperties
set oTasks = oPackage.Tasks

for each oTask in oTasks
    OutputFile.write (vbCrLf)
    OutputFile.write (string(12 + len(oTask.Description), "-"))
    OutputFile.write (vbCrLf)
    OutputFile.write ("-- Task: "  & oTask.Description & " --") 
    OutputFile.write (vbCrLf)
    OutputFile.write (string(12 + len(oTask.Description), "-"))
    OutputFile.write (vbCrLf)

    set oProperties = oTask.Properties

    for each oProperty in oProperties
        OutputFile.write (oProperty.Name & " = [" & trim(oProperty.Value) & "]")
        OutputFile.write (vbCrLf)
    next 
next 

OutputFile.close

set OutputFile = Nothing
set oTasks = Nothing
set oProperties = Nothing
set oPackage = Nothing
set FileSys = Nothing
```

The key is to know the method to load the DTS package from either the file system or SQL Server.

For example

```
...
dim oPackage
set oPackage = CreateObject("DTS.Package2")
oPackage.LoadFromStorageFile strInputFile, "", "", "", ""
...
```

More details can be found on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa197290%28v=sql.80%29.aspx (LoadFromSQLServer Method)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa197287%28v=sql.80%29.aspx (LoadFromStorageFile Method)